# Display not detected on a Thinkpad T420

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, intel-graphics, lenovo

I just upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10  Everything is working except display is listed as "unknown" with max resolution of 1024x786.  Does not give option to go higher.

Laptop is a late model T420 with Intel Graphics.  How can I get this up to native resolution?

Comment: Fixed the issue with the following from an older post on intel graphics

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Reboot

Comment: Have trouble with a second monitor.  XDiagnose reports "Failed to load module "intel"

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)