# VGA not detected on a Lenovo T420

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, lenovo

I have problem with a VGA driver that is not detected on my Lenovo T420 with Ubuntu. 10.04

Output of `lshw`:

```
       *-display UNCLAIMED
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 09
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff(prefetchable) ioport:5000(size=64)
```

This is output from `lspci -nn`:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0116] (rev 09)

When I install version 11 for testing it can detect the drivers:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)

```
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 09
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:42 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

On Ubuntu 10.04, I tried to install the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` driver but I'm still unable to get the right resolution on my display.

I've already tried the suggestion on [Display not detected on a Thinkpad T420](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65903/display-not-detected-on-a-thinkpad-t420), but still no luck.

Comment: sorry on 10.04 this is the output:        *-display UNCLAIMED
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff(prefetchable) ioport:5000(size=64)

Comment: No need to comment it twice, just edit it in and add a single comment so I get notified. Perhaps the older kernel does not support your newer hardware, install the newer version (11.10) unless you really do not want to.

Comment: A bit late now, but would have been nice to know either way if this was an Optimus equipped T240, and your BIOS settings. You may have been on dedicated NVidia.

Answer (score 2):

With the following steps I succeeded to get the Lenovo T420 intel graphic running properly:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-backport-natty linux-headers-generic-lts-backport-natty
```

Then just change the following line in your `/etc/default/grub` (edit as root!)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash i965.modeset=1"
```

don't forget

```
sudo update-grub
```

and of course a reboot!

---

You often can read something about 'i915...' but this seems to be for older Intel graphics (compatibility issues?). I found (somewhere?) the device code for the Intel HD 3000 which is i965.

Comment: that should be "quiet", not "quite".

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that your Intel card is not supported? Both `lshw` output shows that the Intel driver (`i915`) work:

> configuration: **driver=i915** latency=0

The output of `lspci` is missing the names because the data of the PCI devices is outdated. To update your local database of PCI device names, run:

```
sudo update-pciids
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, i got the driver updated name but there is no (configureation:driver=i915 latency=0). it still not detect the driver. any sugguestion please.

Comment: *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff(prefetchable) ioport:5000(size=64)

Comment: from my basic understanding, Intel VGA should create this file: /etc/X11/xorg.conf, i try to locate it on my system it's not there.

Comment: @user32065 `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` does not have to exist, settings are automatically detected.

Comment: what i did i upgrade to kernel 2.6-35.30, it's booting and last screen before login i got black screen. i reboot and enter grup mode, i issue the lshw -C to check the driver and it's exist this time, the problem now i'm getting black screen and if i revert back to old kernel 32-34 i will not get the driver installed. any help please.

Comment: Try upgrading from Lucid to Oneiric

Comment: thanks for your help, but i don't want to upgrade the version it's a matter of driver only.